# Add extra link to google custom search engine result

Tags: google-custom-search

I need to build a search results page, hopefully using a Google Custom Search Engine.  My problem though is that I need to add an extra link or icon to each item in the search result.

It would be an icon to generate a custom short-link for that particular result.

What would be the best way to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add html and stuff to google result,
you couldn't use the simple google custom search engine.

You should use google search api,
and than process the results and display them by yourself to the screen.